# Center Camera Position around Google Maps Markers using Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm using `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.13` to develop a basic 'multiple markers on a google map' type Flutter screen.

I am curious how others set the `initialCameraPostion` for the `GoogleMap()` class. I either

1. Set it static initially
2. In the `getMapMarkers()` function, I will call a `setMarkers(List<dynamic> markers)` (that takes in a list of the markers or objects) and grab one of the `GeoPoint` from the list of markers and use that to set the `initialCameraPosition`.

   ```
    class MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {

     GoogleMapController _mapController;

     // Method #1
     static CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition =
         CameraPosition(target: const LatLng(26.357540, -81.785290), zoom: 12);

     void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
       _mapController = controller;
       _getMapMarkers();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Stack(children: <Widget>[_googleMap(context)]);
     }

     Widget _googleMap(BuildContext context) {
       return Column(children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(
           child: Container(
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             child: GoogleMap(
               initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
               onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
               mapType: MapType.normal,
               markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
             ),
           ),
         )
       ]);
     }
   }

   // Method #2
   void _setCenter(List<dynamic> markers) {
     GeoPoint geo = markers[0].geocode;
     setState(() {
       _initialCameraPosition =
           CameraPosition(target: LatLng(geo.latitude, geo.longitude), zoom: 12);
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi! Have same question. Did you wind any workable solution?

Answer (score 7):

`initialCameraPosition` only for the initial time. You can move the camera using the following way. We already got a camera controller using `onMapCreated` hook.

```
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
    _getMapMarkers();
  }
```

Using This `_mapController` we can access `moveCamera` function and move the camera to marker position.

```
_mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(<LatLng one of your marker position>));
```

Example:

```
_mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(LatLng(markerLat,markerLng)));
```

Comment: I used this code to update my camera position with my current GPS position...it worked, thanks

Comment: You can also you _mapController.animateCamera(...) for a smoother movement